# ReactiveUI with XF: How to create a Command Binder for a custom control?

Tags: xamarin.forms, reactiveui

I am working with **Xamarin Forms** and **ReactiveUI** and trying to bind a custom command from a custom XF control to my view model.

```
this.BindCommand(ViewModel, vm => vm.HasChangesCommand, view => view.socket1);
```

My control socket1 has a Dependency Property Command of type ICommand. However, I'm getting the error:

> "System.Exception: Couldn't find a Command Binder for [ControlName]"

I think I have to create a Command Binder for my control but I can't find any hint on how to do this.
Is there any documentation on how to create a Command Binder for a custom control on **Xamarin Forms**?

EDIT:
I've seen that adding third parameter "eventName" it's working. However I would like to know if there's any way to build that Command Binder so you don't need to specify the event in that call.

Comment: What if you do view.socket1.Command?

Comment: To create "Command Binder" it looks like you have to implement this interface: ICreatesCommandBinding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be able to use `BindCommand` with a custom view, the easiest way is to have a property of type `ICommand` on the view that is named `Command`.  Doing a `OneWayBind` as [Daniel suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52647228/4552766) is also easy, though it's also easy to forget to do that when you're used to using `BindCommand` for command bindings.

If you want to use anything else (an event, gesture recognizer, etc...), you can create an implementation of `ICreatesCommandBinding` that defines how the command is wired up to the target object.  So you can do something like the following:

```cs
public class SocketControl : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty MyCustomCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(MyCustomCommand),
        typeof(ICommand),
        typeof(SocketControl));

    public ICommand MyCustomCommand
    {
        get => (ICommand)GetValue(MyCustomCommandProperty);
        set => SetValue(MyCustomCommandProperty, value);
    }

    //...
}

public sealed class SocketControlCommandBinder : ICreatesCommandBinding
{
    public IDisposable BindCommandToObject(ICommand command, object target, IObservable<object> commandParameter)
    {
        var socket = (SocketControl)target;

        // get the original value so we can restore it when the binding is disposed...
        var originalValue = socket.GetValue(SocketControl.MyCustomCommandProperty);
        var disposable = Disposable.Create(() => socket.SetValue(SocketControl.MyCustomCommandProperty, originalValue));

        // set the control's command to the view-model's command
        socket.SetValue(SocketControl.MyCustomCommandProperty, command);

        return disposable;
    }

    public IDisposable BindCommandToObject<TEventArgs>(ICommand command, object target, IObservable<object> commandParameter, string eventName)
    {
        /// not shown here ...
        return Disposable.Empty;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a positive integer when this class supports BindCommandToObject for this
    /// particular Type. If the method isn't supported at all, return a non-positive integer.
    /// When multiple implementations return a positive value, the host will use the one which
    /// returns the highest value. When in doubt, return '2' or '0'
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type">The type to query for.</param>
    /// <param name="hasEventTarget">If true, the host intends to use a custom event target.</param>
    /// <returns>A positive integer if BCTO is supported, zero or a negative value otherwise</returns>
    public int GetAffinityForObject(Type type, bool hasEventTarget)
    {
        return type.GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(SocketControl).GetTypeInfo()) ? 2 : 0;
    }
}
```

Once you have the command binder created, you need to register it so ReactiveUI knows how to use it.  In your app.xaml.cs (or wherever you create your application):

```cs
Splat.Locator.CurrentMutable.Register(
    () => new SocketControlCommandBinder(),
    typeof(ReactiveUI.ICreatesCommandBinding));
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to do a OneWayBind to the command instead. Your control should then handle the command. Setting enabled if needed and execute command when needed.

this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.HasChangesCommand, view => view.socket1.CommandName);

Comment: Thank you, Wow took me all day to find this